# Getting Round The SubQuery Returned More Than 1 Value Error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a reading of time spent in class, and my query keeps producing the error of

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I get around this?

```
Declare 
@timespentinclass decimal(18,2),
@courseID varchar(50),
@course varchar(50),
@studentID varchar(50),
@count int

Set @courseID = '2'

Create Table Course (course varchar(MAX),coursename varchar(MAX),timespentinclass int,studentID varchar(50),dun int)
Create Table coursesOffered(course varchar(Max),courseIDUsed varchar(50),courseID varchar(50))  
Create Table timespentinclass(coursetaken varchar(Max),studentID varchar(50),studentinfo varchar(MAX),daysattended decimal(18,2))

SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses)

while @count > 0

BEGIN

SET @course = (SELECT TOP 1 course FROM courses WHERE dun IS NULL)
SET @courseID = (SELECT TOP 1 courseIDUsed FROM coursesOffered WHERE courseID = @course)

BEGIN

    set @timespentinclass = (select (convert(decimal(18,2),SUM(daysattended)),2)
    from timespentinclass t
    RIGHT JOIN courses al
    ON t.studentID = al.studentID
    where course = @courseID
    and t.studentID = al.studentID) 

END

update course set
timespentinclass = @timespentinclass    
where course = @course
and dun is null 

set @count = @count - 1     

UPDATE courses
SET dun = 1
WHERE studentID = @studentID

END
```

EDIT 1
Adding in Top 1 to this statement will no longer produce the error, but it gives the same value for timespentinclass for all students for that class?

```
set @timespentinclass = (select Top 1(convert(decimal(18,2),SUM  (daysattended)),2)
from timespentinclass t
RIGHT JOIN courses al
ON t.studentID = al.studentID
where course = @courseID
and t.studentID = al.studentID)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us complete code?

Comment: @Copy/paste from my ssms.  The issue only arises when it hits the set @timespentinclass line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Look at this:

```
(select (convert(decimal(18,2),SUM(daysattended)),    2)
```

Here you are selecting converted value and 2. You are misplaced brackets. I think it should be:

```
set @timespentinclass = (select convert(decimal(18,2), SUM(daysattended), 2)
from timespentinclass t
RIGHT JOIN courses al
ON t.studentID = al.studentID
where course = @courseID
and t.studentID = al.studentID)
```

But I always prefer the following syntax:

```
select @timespentinclass = convert(decimal(18,2), SUM(daysattended), 2)
from timespentinclass t
RIGHT JOIN courses al ON t.studentID = al.studentID
where course = @courseID
```

Comment: Oh Yeah, looks that is it. Big eye +1. again the last line `and t.studentID = al.studentID` is unnecessary. It's redundant.

Comment: @Rahul, yes the key was that sub query returned more ther 1 VALUE, but we both thought that it was error about ROWS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe below code block is creating the issue

```
set @timespentinclass = (select (convert(decimal(18,2),SUM(daysattended)),2)
from timespentinclass t
RIGHT JOIN courses al
```

You can either use `TOP` keyword to get a single data record (OR) declare `@timespentinclass` as a table variable to get around the issue.

Comment: Using top 1 in the line no longer produces the error, but it gives the same value for daysattended for all students for the 1 course.

Comment: @Rahul, it is just a sum without grouping. It should return 1 row. I can not check now  but it looks correct to me.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, Yes I just re-read the post and to me as well. You are absolutely correct. With that either OP haven't posted entire code (OR) there is some mystery.

Comment: @user2676140, can you run the query without `set @timespentinclass =` and see how many rows it returns? It should logically be 1.

Comment: @Rahul - Their are 130 results returned from my Count(Courses) but as you stated only 1 course is entered in the loop at a time.